# How to write elegant Code in Perl

Tags: perl

I’m a Perl beginner and I really love this language. I have written the following little program. This is one of the games on the website Codingame.com.

```
chomp($n=<STDIN>);
if (!$n) {
   print 0;   
} else {
   @t=split/ /,<STDIN>;
   foreach $i(0..$n-1) {
      $m=$t[$i]if(!$m)||(abs($t[$i])<abs($m))||(($t[$i]==-$m)&&($t[$i]>0));    
   }
}print $m;
```

The goal of this code is to give the closest number to 0 of a list, and if there are `-4` and `4` for example, it will always return the positive number.

- `$n` is the number of numbers in the list
- `@t` is the list as an array
- `$m` is the minimum

This code seems to work, but it is difficult to read. I would like to learn some Perl secrets to make it shorter, more elegant, simple and maintainable.

Could you give me advice to rewrite it? Maybe using the ternary operator or a one line `foreach` loop.

I don't really want a perfect code as an answer, but some indications, and then I can search details and learn by myself thanks to your help.

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  It does not suit Stack Overflow because you have working code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code reviews belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code Golf is probably a more appropriate site for this task. Code Review is going to be more concerned with readability/maintainability than pure size.

Comment: You'll want to look at the [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret) documentation which are "secret" operators (really combinations of operators) often used when code golfing in Perl.

Comment: Come to us at PPCG, but you need to have working code first.

Comment: *"This code is working pretty well, and i'm trying to reduce its size"* No. No it's not "working pretty well". Make it work properly first

Comment: I think the good question is to ask the more perlish way to solve this little problem. Here is my solution: my ($best) = sort {abs($a) <=> abs($b) || $b <=> $a} split ' ', <>;print "$best\n";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch!

Please don't start golfing your code before you know the language inside out and can write and thoroughly debug a program

Here are the problems I can see with your code, forgetting for now the stuff you wouldn't use with golfed code

- `@t = split / /, <STDIN>` will split on every space. If the input starts with a space then `@t` will have an empty string in the first element. If there is more than one space between the numbers then `@t` will have empty strings in the middle. The last element will have a trailing newline attached to it because you haven't removed it
- `foreach` and `for` are identical. Most practised Perl programnmers use `for` throughout, and clearly you should do the same if you're golfing
- There's no reason to ask how many numbers will be input. This is a computer that can count them, and `$n = @t` will do fine
- `!$m` is true if `$m` is zero or an empty string, not just when it hasn't been defined. That leads to this bug

  ```
  $ perl coding_game.pl
  2
  0 1
  1
  ```

  But 1 is not nearer to zero than zero!

Then, if you are writing real code

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and declare all your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use
- Use meaningful names for your variables that describe their *purpose*. `$n` is okay, but `@t` is not
- Indent your code properly, and look at [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) to see what would help experienced Perl coders understand what you have written

I suggest something closer to this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

die unless my @numbers = split ' ', <>;

my $best = shift @numbers;

for ( @numbers ) {
    if ( abs $best > abs or $best < 0 and $best == -abs ) {
        $best = $_;
    }
}

print $best, "\n";
```